# In Gin-Rummy, who start after a round was played to the wall?

Tags: gin-rummy

In Gin-Rummy, when the deck reach the last 2 cards and no player have knocked, the rounds end in a draw.

Who starts the next round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same player deals again.  From [thesprucecrafts](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/gin-rummy-complete-card-game-rules-412366)

> If only two cards remain in the draw pile after a player discards and neither player has knocked, the round ends in a draw and the same player deals again.